# Get Euclidian and infinite distance in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, distance

I'm trying to get the Euclidian Distance in Pytorch, using torch.dist, as shown below:

```
torch.dist(vector1, vector2, 1)
```

If I use "1" as the third Parameter, I'm getting the Manhattan distance, and the result is correct, but I'm trying to get the Euclidian and Infinite distances and the result is not right. I tried with a lot of different numbers on the third parameter, but I'm not able to get the desired distances.

How can I get the Euclidian and Infinite distances using Pytorch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `.norm()` instead of `.dist()`.

```
vector1 = torch.FloatTensor([3, 4, 5])
vector2 = torch.FloatTensor([1, 1, 1])

dist = torch.norm(vector1 - vector2, 1)
print(dist) # tensor(9.)
dist = torch.norm(vector1 - vector2, 2)
print(dist) # tensor(5.3852)
dist = torch.norm(vector1 - vector2, float("inf"))
print(dist) # tensor(4.)

dist = torch.dist(vector1, vector2, 1)
print(dist) # tensor(9.)
dist = torch.dist(vector1, vector2, 2)
print(dist) # tensor(5.3852)
dist = torch.dist(vector1, vector2, float("inf"))
print(dist) # tensor(1.)
```

As we can see for the infinity distance, `.norm()` returns the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance is the L2 norm: `torch.dist(vector1, vector2, 2)` 

Inifnity norm: `torch.dist(vector1, vector2, float("inf"))`

Answer (score 0):

`torch.norm` is now deprecated and it is recommended to use `torch.linalg.norm()` instead. The documentation can be found [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/linalg.html#torch.linalg.norm).

The euclidian and infinity distance can be computed with

```
vector1 = torch.FloatTensor([3, 4, 5])
vector2 = torch.FloatTensor([1, 1, 1])
dist_euclidian = torch.linalg.norm(vector1 - vector2)  # tensor(5.3852)
dist_infinity = torch.linalg.norm(vector1 - vector2, float("inf"))  # tensor(4.)
```